# TON compile error c++ cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

```
$ cmake --build . --target test-lite-client
```

На 83% ошибка:

```
[ 83%] Building CXX object crypto/CMakeFiles/ton_block.dir/block/mc-config.cpp.o
In file included from /home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/../validator/interfaces/validator-full-id.h:4:0,
                 from /home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/block/mc-config.h:7,
                 from /home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/block/mc-config.cpp:1:
/home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/../tl/generate/auto/tl/ton_api.h:33:31: error: ‘tl_object_storage’ in namespace ‘ton’ does not name a template type
 using object_storage = ::ton::tl_object_storage<Type>;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/../tl/generate/auto/tl/ton_api.h:36:1: error: ‘object_storage’ does not name a type
 object_storage<Type> create_object(Args &&... args) {
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/../tl/generate/auto/tl/ton_api.h:41:1: error: ‘object_storage’ does not name a type
 object_storage<ToType> move_object_as(FromType &&from) {
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/../tl/generate/auto/tl/ton_api.h:48:29: error: ‘object_storage’ does not name a type
 std::string to_string(const object_storage<T> &value) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/name/TON/lite-client/crypto/../tl/generate/auto/tl/ton_api.h:48:43: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 std::string to_string(const object_storage<T> &value) {
                                           ^
```

Comment: Может компилятор слишком старый? Если нет, пишите баг-репорт разработчикам той штуки, которую компилируете.

Answer (score 0):

На Ubuntu 18.04 собралось, на 16.04 не хотело. Обновляйтесь.